# Is there a difference between `bzr clone`, `bzr branch` and `bzr checkout`?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar

Obviously `bzr clone`, `bzr branch` and `bzr checkout` all do the same thing when given an URL as parameter and executed in a non-bzr directory.

Is there any difference for later Bazaar workflow? i.e. `bzr commit`, `bzr update` and friends.

Comment: Don't use `bzr clone`. Right now it's an alias of `bzr branch` but in the future it could be changed to do different thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Branching and cloning are the same, but branching and checkouts are **not** the same.

```
$ bzr help branch
...
Aliases:  get, clone
See also: checkout
```

Looking over the [Checkout Tutorial](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/CheckoutTutorial), you'll see that a checkout essentially binds every action you take directly to the branch.  So anything you do is essentially `push`ed when you do it -- obviously that's a huge workflow difference.

> ### Difference between a Branch and a Checkout
>
> Let's start by saying there is nothing
>   you can do with a Checkout that you
>   can't do with plain Branches. A
>   Checkout just enables different
>   defaults and workflow helpers.
>
> ### What does Checkout do
>
> With a Checkout, whenever you create
>   new entries in a local Branch, it also
>   creates them in a remote Branch. This
>   corresponds to commands like `bzr
>   commit` and `bzr pull`. If you attempt to
>   commit a new changes, and the remote
>   Branch has a different state than the
>   local one, it will prevent you, and
>   let you know that you are out of date.
>   You can use `bzr update` to apply the
>   remote changes locally.

Comment: so checkout switches bzr to a svn-like mode, losing all the benefits of distributed version control

Comment: @knittl: not all, because you can still make another branch of your checkout, for example... And one strong point of Bazaar is that it offers a variety of workflows, the checkout one might reassure people coming from centralized VCSes.

Comment: In addition to PhiLho's points, checkouts can allow one to have multiple feature branches without needing to have a working tree for each one. By using `bzr switch` rather than `cd <branch-dir>` to switch between branches, the code can always be in the same directory. This can be handy for using tools such as IDEs, or serving up a local version of a web project.

Comment: @knittl In addition, you can browse history, annotate, and make diffs while offline. If you want to commit wihtou connection you can unbind (so it instantaneously becomes a regular branch) and then commit.

Answer (score 4):

`bzr branch` and `bzr checkout` do very different things.  They both give you a working tree, but `bzr checkout` gives you *only* a working tree; commits and updates work directly on/from the source repository.  `bzr branch` gives you a working tree of a new branch of the repository; commits on this branch will not be automatically applied to the source branch.  I'm not sure on `clone`.

**Update**: according to the comment, `checkout` gives you the full history; that seems right. Semantically, `checkout` looks and feels like a centralized VCS checkout with the branch locally; it implements this by keeping a local history (which you can browse offline - a plus), but linking it back to the original history so you can only commit when you're up-to-date and commits get automatically pushed. Moreover, it is possible to commit without connection by unbinding the checkout, in which case it becomes a regular branch.

Comment: This is wrong. bzr checkout is essentially bzr branch + bzr bind. You do get a full branch and you can for instance browse log, diffs and history while offline. The lightweight checkout is what gives you just a tree.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have said, "bzr checkout" is a superset of "bzr clone/branch", in that "bzr checkout" creates a *bound branch*. Bound branches pull from the source repo whenever an update operation is performed and push to the source repo whenever a commit is performed.

To bind a cloned branch or unbind a checked-out branch, use "bzr bind"/"bzr unbind".